# Proving that the mean of a random variable is continuous, where is dominated convergence being used?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am looking at the proof of the first part of this lemma.

[image]

Previously in the text another theorem was stated: Convergence in distribution, $Y_n \implies Y$, holds iff $Ef(Y_n) \rightarrow Ef(Y)$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$.

So now I am wondering where is dominated convergence being used? it seems to me that for any $t_n$ we have $W(t_n) \rightarrow W(t)$ by continuity and then $EW(t_n) \rightarrow EW(t)$ follows from the theorem I stated above.

Comment: If you are taking $f$ to be the identity function  here, it is not bounded.

Comment: Oh thanks! but then how does the argument proceed in the proof?

Comment: Using the dominated convergence theorem, which guarantees that the limit of the integral/expectation is the integral/expectation of the pointwise limit, as long as a the sequence of random variables is dominated by a quantity itself integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb E[||W||_{\infty}]<\infty \Rightarrow W(t_n)$ is bounded for all $t_n$ Thus, $W(t_n)$ is bounded in $L^1$

$W(t_n)\to W(t)$, and $W(t_n)$ bounded in $L^1$ allow us to conclude that $W(t_n)\to W(t)$ in $L^1$

so, $\Bbb E[W(t_n)]\to \Bbb E[W(t)]$ by a straight forward application of DCT

so, let $|t_n-t|<\delta$ then, $|\Bbb E[W(t_n)] - \Bbb E[W(t)]|<\epsilon$ by $L^1$ convergence.

Thus, $|\mu(t_n)-\mu(t)|<\epsilon$ when $|t_n-t|<\delta \Rightarrow$ continuity of $\mu$

Using convergence of distribution would not be appropriate here since:

$1$. $t_n$ is not a random variable, so we can not really talk about $t_n$ converging in distribution having anything to do with $\Bbb E[W(t_n)]$ converging.

$2$. We aren't given any sequence of distribution functions/ told anything about a sequence of distribution functions converging